# Print statement not called in anonymous class passed to class constructor

Tags: java, anonymous-class

I have two classes and one interface.

Interface:

```
public interface MyBirthdayEvent {
    void itsMyBirthday();
}
```

First class:

```
public class MyBirthdayButton
{
   public void addOnClickedListener(MyBirthdayEvent mbe){} 
}
```

Second class:

```
public class MyBirthday {

    private MyBirthdayButton myBirthdayButton = new MyBirthdayButton();

    MyBirthday() {
        myBirthdayButton.addOnClickedListener(new MyBirthdayEvent() {

        public void itsMyBirthday() {
            System.out.println("Happy Birthday");
    }           

    });
    }
}
```

Then in main, I have this:

```
public class TestThisStuff {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    MyBirthday myBirthday = new MyBirthday();

    }
}
```

As can be seen from the code, I am using an anonymous class in the MyBirthday constructor.  In doing so, I am trying to get the string `"Happy Birthday"` to print to the console.

My problem is, when I call the `MyBirthday` constructor in main by making a new myBirthday object, I am not seeing the string `"Happy Birthday"` print to the console.  Shouldn't it print to the console?  If not, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: So the constructor of `MyBirthday` adds the `onClilckedListener`. What exactly invokes said method? Is this supposed to be hooked into a GUI like Swing? As the code stands now, nothing is going to invoke the method. Unless I'm just not reading something correctly.

Comment: In main, when I call the constructor, shouldn't it call the print statement since the print statement lives within the constructor?

Comment: The print statement is not in the constructor, it is in the method `itsMyBirthday()` that is no where invoked (as the answers have pointed out). Either invoke the method, or move the print statement to actually be in the constructor.

Comment: You should invoke itsMyBirthday() method in able to see the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is this:

```
public interface MyBirthdayEvent {
    void itsMyBirthday();

    default void invoke() {
        itsMyBirthday();
    }
}
```

...

```
public class MyBirthdayButton
{
   public void addOnClickedListener(MyBirthdayEvent mbe){
       mbe.invoke();

   } 
}
```

...

Also, it will work without it, but use a lambda rather than an anonymous inner class.  This looks much better.

```
MyBirthday() {
        myBirthdayButton.addOnClickedListener(() -> 
                                       System.out.println("Happy Birthday"));
    }
```

Comment: Nice use of the interface default and the recommendation for the lambda.

Answer (score 1):

you can move `System.out.println("some words")`statement to your `MyBirthdayEvent`constructor

it didn't show in your console because you haven't invoke the method